# Linking CXX shared library

Tags: ros, rospackage, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i have installed few packages and trying to build them using the "make" command and i am getting a linking error....
the code:

"Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libactionlib.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lros
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../lib/libactionlib.so] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/maneesh/ros_stacks/common/actionlib/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/actionlib.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/maneesh/ros_stacks/common/actionlib/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/maneesh/ros_stacks/common/actionlib/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2"

how do i go about and eliminate the error?

regards,

maneesh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12199/linking-cxx-shared-library/) by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-12-04**:
If you want to use actionlib in your project, the correct thing to do is add a dependency to your own package's manifest.xml; then linking and everything else will work.

**Comment by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on 2011-12-03**:
I also run the rosmake command, and i see no failures in that list....

**Comment by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on 2011-12-03**:
well, i am installing a package called "common" from the ros.org for my project related to gazebo simulator. There is this sub folder called actionlib inside the main package. I tried to run the make command in "/home/maneesh/ros_stacks/common/actionlib/" directory and the above error showed up....

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-12-03**:
Can you tell us what, exactly, you did to cause this error? Which package are you building? Also, try using 'rosmake'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If rosmake passes with no errors, then if you rerun make in the package it should be working now, since rosmake calls make in that package and all dependents in the right order.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on 2011-12-04**:
When i ran the rosmake command, i get :  [rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 23 packages with 0 failures.  but right after that if i run the make command, i get the same error as i mentioned above....

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-29**:
@Maneesh please provide more details how to reproduce the error.  Your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and where you have installed everything would be helpful.  Please edit your question to include these at the bottom.